# Why my site showing internal server error while creating build on production server in next.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js

I am hosting a Next.js app on custom server and managing it as a process manager using pm2.

Everything is working well except when I am pushing changes to server and trying to create build using npm run build website stop working and showing internal server error till build finish.

My main problem is how I can still build the Next.js while still making the previous build available until the current build is complete.

Thanks!

Comment: I have same issue. Did you fix it?

Comment: me too... does anyone have a solution?